# what's the difference between "apparent", "evident" and "obvious"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, adjectives

I believe they are all the same, but is there any case in which not all of them are correct?

Here are the examples, from an English textbook:

> **1. It is (quite) *_*_ that he took the wrong path.**
>
> A.apparent B.evident C.stupid D.absurd
>
> **2. It is *_*_ that two and two make four.**
>
> A.apparent B.evident C.obvious D.visible
>
> **3. It is *_*_ (that) you have been cheated.**
>
> A.clear B.apparent C.regretful D.ignorant

The answers are B, C, and A.

I think A is also a correct answer to Q1, A and B are also correct answers to Q2, and B is also a correct answer to Q3.

It is not that easy when it comes to answering questions in an exam, because there is only one answer I can choose, and if I'm wrong, I lose points. So, is it really wrong to use the other words in these cases? Why?

Comment: [“Obvious” vs. “Evident”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44339) answers most of this, and also see  [Is there a difference between “seemingly” and “apparently”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44335)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.It is (quite) __ that he took the wrong path.
>
> A.apparent B.evident C.stupid D.absurd
>
> 2.It is __ that two and two make four.
>
> A.apparent B.evident C.obvious D.visible
>
> 3.It is __ (that) you have been cheated.
>
> A.clear B.apparent C.regretful D.ignorant
>
> And the answers are B C A.

I agree with these as being the correct answers, by far the best although the alternatives are reasonable and in some cases only ring slight bells of warning...
It is however very hard to explain why, as it is a matter of idiom, or patterns we are used to.  But here goes...

1. apparent would mean it is (patently) clear - in this case the fundamental meaning that it appears in front of you rather than the less literal meaning in the sense of "appearances can be deceptive".  That it is evident rather than apparent follows from the proposal being past and not something that is visible now (whether deceptive or not). stupid and absurd are not quite the correct/complete construction - it is stupid of him to have taken the wrong path; it is stupid to think that he took the wrong path; it is absurd to think that he would have taken the wrong path.
2. apparent would mean there is room for doubt, and opportunity is being provided to argue or disprove; evident also means there is some evidence and a conclusion has been drawn, although self-evident, like obvious, could be used to indicate that no evidence is needed other than seeing (and counting what is as obvious as, indeed part of, the hand in front of your face).
3. apparent would mean there is room for doubt and I would expect a but to follow; clear (or obvious) is much more certain and doesn't have the same degree of expectation that you will go on to further explore the truth of the matter. Then regretful should be regretable, and ignorant doesn't fit either with the third person or the (that) clause: He is ignorant about your being cheated, etc.

The only alternative other than the specified correct answer that is plausible is 3B - and that just doesn't sound finished.

Answer (score 4):

A look in a decent dictionary should answer this...

Apparent is direct - think of *appear*. You can see it is so. You cannot see David ~ "It is apparent that David is not here."

Evident is indirect - think of *evidence*. David did not sign in and nobody saw him ~ "Evidently David was not here."

Obvious is something that is clearly true. You cannot see David in the room ~ "David is obviously not in this room."

Comment: I actually have a rough idea about their meanings. The only thing I'm asking is what's the difference of its usage, and I will give some examples in my question.

Comment: But the meanings, nicely and succinctly summarized here, give clear indications of how they are to be used.

Comment: +1 for figuring out the reasons why the examiners chose these as the correct answers (although I don't think *evident* needs to be indirect, although *apparent* probably shouldn't be).

Answer (score 3):

The word "obvious" should be reserved for things that are patently obvious, like:

> You obviously have a nose.

*Obvious* works best when it is evident to the mind or logically apparent. The word comes from the Latin *via*, which means way.

> You apparently have a nose.

By the looks of it, you do. *Apparent* works best when the thing literally appears in sight. That's the Latin meaning at least. In this case, I should not be too surprised about your nose being visible, and because of that, the second sentence carries sarcastic overtones (more so than the first).

> You evidently have a nose.

If our language was logical, it would be good form to use *evidently* with some evidence. There is no reason to believe you should obviously have a nose. But, I have a paper here that says that you do have one. Apparently, your face is completely flat. But evidently, you have a nose.

However, that meaning of *evidently* is evidently obsolete, according to the Oxford English Dictionary. *Evident* and *apparent* are close synonyms, without much differentiation in modern usage. A quick [Google N-Gram comparison](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=obvious,%20apparent,%20evident&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) shows that *evident*, which used to be the most popular of the three, became the least popular in the 1930s.

All three are frequently suspect as "[weasel words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aManual_of_Style/Words_to_watch)," meaningless and used when things are neither apparent, evident, or obvious.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborated answer! Could you please also tell me how do you think of the three examples I listed?

Comment: I am sorry to say, the people who wrote that test do not speak English well. All of the options are plausible, except for 2.D and 3.D.

Comment: Alright then, it seems that I was overthinking it, which happens a lot to me.

Comment: @denten, besides 2D and 3D, 1C also is marginal (ie would not be said by a native speaker).

Comment: Denten, I am puzzled by your comment that the test writers do not speak English well. There is a real differentiation between the words. The questions emphasize that although they are similar, there are legitimate reasons to choose one over another. Strangely enough, your primary answer suggests that you do understand this, yet your comment suggests otherwise. Yes, all of the options are "plausible," as you put it, but each one is slightly -- and not trivially -- different. (I won't add an answer myself, because the answers already given [including yours] have already made my point.)

Comment: @JohnM.Landsberg --agreed on differentiation (however slight), but the test does not ask to differentiate. The choices given are all more or less correct, with the exception of two.

Comment: @jwpat7 "It is stupid that he ____" is acceptable although informal. It yields .4 mil results on Google if that tells you anything.

Comment: I have to agree with denten that these are not good questions.  Question 2 alone is clear. Question 1 could be A or B. If I see John down on the beach when I am at the top of the cliff, it's apparent he took the wrong path to reach me. If he has not arrived and I see his bicycle on the beach it's evident he took the wrong path, but it's not apparent. Without context either is correct. Question 3 could be A or B. Clear and apparent have almost the same meaning in this context.

Comment: Context IS important, and lack of it makes this discussion even more complicated than it probably need be. Consider that we don't REALLY know what the test questions are looking for. If the introductory material says, "Choose the BEST answer," there could be plenty of debate. If it says, "Choose the most judgmental answer," the argument goes off in another direction. But if it says, "Choose the best word from these three," as we assume it does, then why are all three not given as potential answers in each case? Q3, in fact, has only ONE of the three as a possible answer. Why is that?

Comment: @JohnM.Landsberg not sure why you think only one is correct in Q3. It is clear that you have been cheated. It is apparent that you have been cheated. It is regretful that you have been cheated. All of these work equally well, no matter how the question is formulated.

Comment: No, no. I'm not saying only one is correct. What I said was, only one of the three words in question (apparent, evident, obvious) is made AVAILABLE as a possible answer. The four possible answers to Q3 include "apparent," but not "evident" or "obvious." So if the point is to learn to differentiate these three words, Q3 fails. And THAT makes me wonder how the question was framed. Maybe it's not just differentiating those three words. Maybe the question is different, like "Which of these answers is illogical?" No, it's NOT likely, but it's food for thought; reread my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

Trickiest is *apparent* or *apparently* - these are used whether something appears to be the case at first sight or on the surface (*superficially*) but in fact you are inclined to *doubt* it - that is you suspect that in truth it is *not* the case.  In a sense such statements are weak assertions, but there is a negative strength due to the *dubious* overtones (you are expressing doubt).

Intermediate is *evident* or *evidently* - these imply that you have some evidence that something is the case and in fact you are inclined to believe it - that is you suspect that in truth the assertion holds.  In a sense such statements are stronger assertions, but there is a negativity due to deliberately opening the statement up for contradiction by further evidence.

Stronger still is *obvious* or *obviously* - these imply that there is little room for doubt.  Nonetheless the fact that something is thought obvious (even by a great many people) does not mean that it is actually true.  In science (or linguistics), we often take the obvious and try to formally prove or disprove it.  Sometimes we find that the obvious is false, or only a first approximation, and a new theory supplants the old. Or putting it another way, we start to believe theories that are very non-obvious or counter-intuitive (think relativity, quantum mechanics, round earth, earth going round the sun; words and sentences are concepts in linguistics that do not have an obvious definition that survives across languages).

To add another case, *supposed* or *supposedly* - imply that something is thought to be the case and leaves room for doubt (with the -s- pronounced /z/), but trickily *supposed to* can mean that something should be the case, is expected to be the case, or is meant to be the case (with the -s- pronounced /s/).  Here we have two different connotations depending on whether we pronounce it with a voiced or unvoiced sibilant (/s/ or /z/).

"She was supposed to have killed him!" has two different meanings depending on how you pronounce it.

Regarding the test and dropping the brackets since those words make a difference:

1. It is quite __ that he took the wrong path.

A.apparent B.evident C.stupid D.absurd

A - you would say: apparently he took the wrong path.
B - most likely, especially with 'quite', implying looking at evidence.
C - not so good in a passive context: he is stupid for taking the wrong path.
D - not so good: It is quite absurd to think that he took the wrong path.

2. It is __ that two and two make four.

A.apparent B.evident C.obvious D.visible

A&B are unlikely as it is not something you normally see or need evidence for.
C is most likely.
ABD might occur with a diagram but are still awkward: this diagram makes visible the obvious and self-evident fact that two and [plus] two makes four.

3. It is __ that you have been cheated.

A.clear B.apparent C.regretful D.ignorant

A is most likely, passing a judgement based on the evidence (evidently would work).
B would be possible but less definite, but again given the judgement isn't final yet would be more likely stated as: Apparently you have been cheated.
C would be stated as: It is regrettable that you have been cheated. (Or in an active form.)
D would be more like: [you are plain] ignorant if you think that you have been cheated.