# Exercies on right usage of english words

Tags: word-choice

Could you find out, where are from the [current exercises](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/106846/whats-the-difference-between-apparent-evident-and-obvious) or advice a similar text book?

I have problems with determining right usage of different words, and such textbook will be quite useful for me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for resources

Comment: Sorry, I don't know, that it is denied. Nevertheless, the primary mean of my question was "find out resource", not "request for resource".

Comment: I don't know what difference you see between "find out resource" and "request for resource". We have [a page on ELU meta](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/484/) listing some "reference" publications that can be consulted to establish *specific* points about usage, but they're not normally packaged as *training courses*. The same principle (requests for resources are Off Topic) applies at [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), but for questions which *are* on topic you will probably get more appropriate answers there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many textbooks which have vocabulary exercises. Some of them are

[English Vocabulary in Use](http://www.slideshare.net/TynaFilimon/english-book-english-vocabulary-in-use-elementary-cambridge-14937263) with offers a few textbooks of different stages of knowledge or [Advanced Laguage Practice](http://www.tlu.ee/~argoi/eng/advanced%20language%20practice.pdf) where you have both grammar and vocabulary exercises.